# Agora Real Time Messaging

Tags: android, agora.io

As we have downloaded the Real Time Messaging (Beta) & then we ran the demo but at the apk run time it asks us to give a UserId (Account), so I do have a confusion in that so can you suggest me what would be the userid (Account) for real time messaging?

Answer (score 1):

The Agora Real-Time Messaging is on open beta so you will need to have it activated on your account. Can you please send an email to **devrel@agora.io** with a brief explanation of your use-case and the appId you wish to enable the service on.